# c# compare two arrays with conditions

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

If i have two arrays

```
   First: A, B, C
   Second: ?, B, C
```

I want to compare only items from Second with items from First which is does not contains question mark "?".

So for such case:

```
   First: A, B, C
   Second: ?, B, C
```

I wan to compare just items 1 and 2 because item 0 in the Second array contains ?.

For that one:

```
   First: A, B, C
   Second: 2, ?, C
```

I want to compare only items 0 and 2 because item 1 in Second array contains ?

Any ideas how better and with minimum amount of code to do that? If it would required to create any lists or any another collections that is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ from the comfort of your armchair:

```
// Input data:
var first = new[] { "A", "B", "?" };
var second = new[] { "?", "B", "C" };

// This actually filters out pairs where either first or second
// is equal to "?". If you only want to filter out pairs where the
// second is "?", adjust accordingly.
var toCompare = first.Zip(second, Tuple.Create)
                     .Where(t => t.Item1 != "?" && t.Item2 != "?");

// And now you have a collection of Tuple<string, string>, which
// can be processed in a multitude of ways:
Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format(
    "Compared {0} items, and found {1} of them equal.",
    toCompare.Count(),
    toCompare.All(t => t.Item1 == t.Item2) ? "all" : "not all"));
```

**Update:**

If the comparison predicate (the method that compares a pair of items and returns a boolean) is going to be more complicated than the above, it makes sense to define it either as a lambda (if it's not going to be reused and it's short enough) or as a proper method otherwise.

For example, to implement what's mentioned in a comment below:

```
Func<Tuple<string, string>, bool> predicate = t =>
    t.Item2 == "?" ||
    t.Item2 == "_" && t.Item1 != string.Empty ||
    t.Item2 == t.Item1;

// And now you have a collection of Tuple<string, string>, which
// can be processed in a multitude of ways:
Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format(
    "Compared {0} items, and found {1} of them equal.",
    toCompare.Count(),
    toCompare.All(predicate) ? "all" : "not all"));
```

Comment: that is great, but one more thing, if for example Second would contain some special element lets say '_' which would mean that related element in array First should be any character except blank. How i may add such spacial condition there?

Comment: I think i get it `.Where(t => t.Item2 != "?" && t.Item2 != "_" || (t.Item2 == "_" && t.Item1 == ""));`

Answer (score 3):

KISS

```
for(int i = 0; i < listB.length; i++)
   if(listB[i] != "?")
       compare(listA[i], listB[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something other than the following?

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < second.Length; ii++)
{
    if (second[ii] == "?")
        continue;

    // Else do your compare.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestArrayWithConditions()
{
    var First = new [] {"A", "B", "C"};
    var Second = new[] { "?", "B", "C" };
    var Third = new[] { "2", "?", "C" };

    var result12 = CompareWithConditions(First, Second);
    var result13 = CompareWithConditions(First, Third);

    Assert.AreEqual(null, result12[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, result12[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, result12[2]);

    Assert.AreEqual(false, result13[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(null, result13[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, result13[2]);
}

private static List<bool?> CompareWithConditions(string[] first, string[] second)
{
    var result = new List<bool?>();

    var length = Math.Min(first.Length, second.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (second[i] == "?")
        {
            result.Add(null);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(second[i] == first[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```